# HAXM - The system requirements are not satisfied. - VMX support

Tags: android

I am installing HAXM, an app required for running android emulator. So I downloaded it, then ran `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\silent_install` and got this:

```
Intel HAXM installation failed!
For more details, please check the installation log: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_install-20220803_2104.log
```

The content of the .log file mentioned in the output is:

```
Version: 7.6.5
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM
Extract: checktool.exe... 100%
Execute: C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          -  AuthenticAMD
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       -  No
VMX enabled         *  Yes
EPT supported       *  Yes
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.19044
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
The system requirements are not satisfied.
```

So only two requirements to fix. But I guess VMX supported one has to do with hardware components. It cannot be fixed using some software or something like that. Or is it?
Yes, this is what my question about. I need explanation on VMX support and how to fix it if possible. If impossible then I can stop searching the internet everywhere and try using physical device for testing instead.

--**EDIT**--

My laptop is new so I didn't know how to take screenshots yet. But I can copy. Here are *Device specifications*:

```
Device name LAPTOP-PR43D4O7
Processor   AMD Ryzen 3 3250U with Radeon Graphics            2.60 GHz
Installed RAM   4.00 GB (3.45 GB usable)
Device ID   CE90BB96-CD65-40D0-9660-54360FF1205A
Product ID  00327-31095-37859-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
```

I have VT-x enabled in BIOS [by default](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1043786/)

> （4）You can see [Intel (VMX) Virtualization Technology], the default setting is Enabled

According to this [wiki](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-Installation-Environment-Check-and-Configurations), I have support for VMX on my device

> HAXM only supports installation on CPUs with Intel VT-x support. Please check Intel VT-x support status.
> Task Manager > Performance Tab (If Virtualization cannot be seen, it means that Intel VT-x is not supported.)

I could find "Virtualization" in performance tab and it was enabled.(I wish I could take screenshot to confirm)

And according to the logged data I mentioned earlier in this question, I can see this line `Hyper-V disabled    *  Yes` which means Hyper-V is disabled and causes no problem. Although I can't reach it when turning windows features on or off. It's not there.

Comment: I've never found haxm working at amd or I'm not sure what i'm saying.
First, I have ryzen 3700x and 5500U on my laptop, both work with android emulator. 

The only thing is needed is to enable virtualisation in bios (3700x, 5500u has it enabled) and then disable hypervisor platform under windows. (You will find it under add/remove programs->program features). That's the thing that sometimes need to be off for virtualbox to work, otherwise it blocks android studio.

PS: I assume you have hypervisor disabled/enabled. Provide us with your CPU and test the above feature under windows.

Comment: @Elboyler Me too. I have ryzen 3 3250U. But I have virtualisation enabled and HyperVisor disabled. Only if I can fix VMX supported and CPU vendor thing..

Comment: Smells for me. I just wonder why the hell you have Intel folder inside your program files. Seems like you have tried to install something, driver maybe. I am not finding any Intel directory in my 5500U system. No clue. I remember that at 3700X i had to reinstall android studio or at least reboot the machine every time i changed supervisor/virtualisation status.

Comment: sdkmanager created that folder while I was following tutorials. I didn't know intel processor was required. For me, I rebooted the system so many times until I realised that supervisor/virtualisation status is unchangable at my bios. At least it is enabled.

Comment: So did you find another way to run virtual device?

Comment: I had HAXM errors only at 3700X and I fixed them by turning supervisor on/off. I assume these errors were visible but emulator just worked, because errors appeared only during install. Maybe just start the emulator and it will work. I feel like it has nothing to do with the errors from android studio. Emulator will fail for sure if hypervisor is "on" or maybe off. Just check both variants by running the emulator.
PS: You have not enough memory. At 16GB of ram android will eat 12-14gb, the less the worse.

Comment: In my case, the emulator didn't work with HAXM. I did some research and found another useful program that did the job. It was late yesterday midnight. BTW, I an using VS code for developing apps. I uninstalled Android Studio after I realised that I could do everything using its command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [somewhere else](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#choose-windows-hypervisor). I got the link from running `emulator @test` when the accelration program was missing. I tried to recreate the problem deleting the program again but couldn't. Anyway, I did mention that my CPU is AMD one, But HAXM is only supported for intel devices. And since Hypervisor is disabled by default and I can't make it enabled, I choosed to use "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors".

> You have an AMD processor and do not need to run Hyper-V at the same time as the Android Emulator.    Use Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors.

So, maybe I took the wrong decision tring to install HAXM on AMD processor.